Arabic Not Rendered Like In quran.com
I am trying to make my text look like quran.com.
Which is (https://quran.com/14/40):

I am using the following HTML.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ar">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Quranic Ayah</title>
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: 'Scheherazade', serif;
            direction: rtl;
            text-align: right;
            font-feature-settings: "liga" 1;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <p>رَبِّ اجۡعَلۡنِىۡ مُقِيۡمَ الصَّلٰوةِ وَمِنۡ ذُرِّيَّتِىۡ​​ ۖ رَبَّنَا وَتَقَبَّلۡ دُعَآءِ‏ ٤٠</p>
</body>

</html>

What I am getting instead is:

I have marked the issues in red.
How can I fix it so that it looks like quran.com

This may be a font issue (most likely, as what I see is somewhat different from your image), and/or you may need to set font-feature-settings dlig and/or hlig as well as liga.

Are you using the same font?

The font in the website is IndoPak. I also tried with that. The last number at the end of the ayat is a symbol drawn in msword (I am not sure how to draw it in html). Moreover, i am not understanding how to draw the exact thing which is in the middle (it might also be a symbol). Being said that, I looked at the hexdump -C and od -c and it has something to do with Zero Width Space, U+200B. If you want, I can paste the hexdumps.

This following code not totally but mostly solved my issue font-family: '_PDMS_Saleem_QuranFont', 'AlQuran IndoPak by QuranWBW', serif;
